# Passing ASP.NET User by Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In my web application I have various components that need to access the currently authenticated user (HttpContext.User).

There are two obvious ways a component can access this:
1) Accessing getting the User from HttpContext.Current
2) Passing the user around in constructors

1. Is not ideal because it makes testing difficult and ties application components to web concerns, when they really shouldn't know about it.
2. Is just messy and complicates everything.

So I've been thinking about passing in the current user (or perhaps just the name/id) to any component that needs it using an IoC container (via dependency injection).

Is anyone using this technique to supply the current ASP.NET user to parts of the application?  Or, Does this sound like a sensible approach? I would like know how this has worked out for people.

Thanks

UPDATE:
Thanks to Raj for a great example. If anyone has a similar example using AutoFac it would be much appreciated!

UPDATE2: Thanks for the answers, wish I could have split the accept!

Comment: @Oded.  Yeah, doesn't look great does it! I accepted three more answers this morning, but it's not showing on my stats yet (guess they are updated by batch).  I've only started posting questions recently, and wanted to wait for more answer to some of the questions before I accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In autofac:

builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).HttpRequestScoped();

Answer (score 1):

What about using the IPrincipal which also contains the IIdentity instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8kt7fb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8kt7fb8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

--updated--

```
private static void AddSecurityConcernsTo(IWindsorContainer container)
{
    container.Register(Component.For<IIdentity>()
      .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
      .UsingFactoryMethod(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity));

    container.Register(Component.For<IPrincipal>()
      .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
      .UsingFactoryMethod(() => HttpContext.Current.User));

    container.Register(Component.For<HttpSessionStateBase>()
        .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session)));

}
```

ref: http://blog.coreycoogan.com/tag/controller-ioc/

Comment: You'd still have to use HttpContext.Current in this case right?

Comment: This looks great, thank you.  If anyone has a similar example using AutoFac it would be very much appreciated!